# What part of template to edit to remove category name from the top of posts?

Tags: posts, templates

In the “Twenty Twenty” template I cannot figure out how to remove the display of category name(s) from the top of posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's a filter for that](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5.3/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/template-parts/content-cover.php#L57). In a plugin or child theme,

```php
add_filter( 'twentytwenty_show_categories_in_entry_header', '__return_false' );
```